# Do I lose a card if I roll 3 bad luck symbols and spend some of them?

Tags: cv

If I buy Pension, which costs two bad luck symbols, do I still suffer misfortune because I initially rolled 3 bad luck symbols? The rules state that you select cards as step 2 and then resolve bad luck as step 3. It says

> for every 3 bad luck symbols which a player has from dice and tokens, the player suffers misfortune

So, does he still "have" them when he's spent them to select the cards in step two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you still suffer it. Clarified on the back of the [rulebook](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/95485/english-rulebook):

> 60. Pension 
>       – This card costs 2 bad luck. If the player rolled 
>       3
>       bad luck (causing misfortune and the loss of some card), 
>       the
>       player can still use 2 of those bad lucks to buy this card

Although it's true that misfortune happens after buying cards but before adding them to your CV, which is a very weird phrasing indeed, you have to suffer it even if you had previously "spent" two bad luck faces for the pension. Spending dice doesn't mean that you never rolled them.